# How do I properly use AWS Temporary Security Credentials with AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) and Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-sts, aws-acm

I am using terraform to manage some ALBs and the Listeners belonging to them. One of the listeners needs to specify a `certificate_arn` which I am trying to obtain from a data source with

```
certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.https_cert.arn
```

in the `aws_lb_listener` spec and the data source like so:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "https_cert" {
  domain = var.aws_route53_domain
}
```

My company uses temporary security credentials by exporting all the necessary environment variables before running terraform commands. However, when trying to obtain this ACM Certificate as a data source, I get an error mentioning `...The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service`. Researching this error, the recommended fix is to complete account verification, but that doesn't really apply when using temporary security credentials, right? Does ACM just not work with temporary creds, or am I missing something else?